# I want to make a firewall rule to allow smooch.io on my server

Tags: chat, firewall, webhooks, chatbot, smooch

I am trying to configure webhook connection to my server but smooch is not able to connect( firewall policies). I need to allow smooch IP but the ping test returns different IP address all the times.

Is there any set of IP(s) which I can allow in the firewall directly?

Comment: as per the documentation, we have 3 IP's to be allowed for weChat. For webHook, I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smooch does not currently have a static set of IPs from which it sends webhooks, but the team is actively working on supporting this.

If you absolutely need static IPs in the meantime to bypass your firewall, you would need to host your own server outside the firewall that relays Smooch webhooks from a static IP that you've configured yourself. Then, configure Smooch to send webhooks to your proxy server instead of your real server.